# unresolved external symbol when using QCharts with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I'm using Qt 5.7 and installing QCharts using the included Maintenance tool. I am able to include QChart and QLineSeries since those two files are in my includes directory however I am recieving a LNK2001 error. I believe this to be due to the program not linking to the libraries, however Qt5Charts is located in my Qt lib folder. QT VS tools has a module selection tool, but QCharts is not included in those modules. Is there anyway to manually include the QCharts Module?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "visualization.h"
#include <QChart>
#include <QLineSeries>

QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE

Visualization::Visualization(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    QLineSeries *series = new QLineSeries();
}
```

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class QColor __cdecl QtCharts::QXYSeries::color(void)const " (?color@QXYSeries@QtCharts@@UEBA?AVQColor@@XZ) Visualization   C:\Users\Lee Dumaliang\Google Drive\Old Dominion\Senior\MSIM 488\Visualization\Visualization\visualization.obj  1
```

Comment: Did you add `QT += charts` to your .pro?

Comment: I included that to my .pro however still getting the error. Do I need to modify the Visual Studio project to take into consideration the .pro file change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: I generated a new .pro file by using the VS Qt tools. I modified this .pro file and included `Qt += charts`. I then regenerated the .vcxproj file using the updated .pro file

Answer (score 1):

Just had a similar issue with VS2019 that this fix didn't work for. For anyone else who has this issue what worked for me was adding "charts" to Properties->Qt Project Settings->QtModules.